# Ссылки на медиатеку в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть самописный сайт который сейчас работает и его решили перенести на Wordpress. Перенос производится в ручную, то есть копируется каждый файл, переносится в медиатеку и потом на него делается ссылка уже на новом сайте.
Суть вопроса в том, что ссылки на все файлы находящиеся в медиатеке wordpress ведут на пример по пути -  www.testweb.com.ua/wp-content.... но будут ли работать данные ссылки когда сайт переедет на рабочий домен - www.workweb.com.ua/wp-content... без test. ?

Comment: Раз уж вы все равно каждое фото переносите вручную, почему бы это не делать из интерфейса самого Вордпресса, редактируя каждую статью, указывая каждую картинку вручную? В таком случае Вордпресс всё сам настроит. Сколько всего статей на сайте - это будет слишком трудоёмко?

Comment: Статей и файлов очень много, это pdf файлы.
Просто сейчас все пути к файлам вот такие, на пример - www.testweb.com.ua/wp-content... а сайт будет работать по ссылке - www.workweb.com.ua, соответственно и путь к файлам поменяется на - www.workweb.com.ua/wp-content...

Comment: Да все нормально должно быть. В админке WP в `Настройки -> Медиафайлы` находится поле для ввода адреса папки, куда будут загружаться медиафайлы. По умолчанию она идёт как `wp-content/uploads`. На одном из моих сайтов, где стоит WP (на выделенном сервере) я указал прямой путь к папке от корневого каталога на сервере: `/srv/www/*****.info/httpdocs/wp-content/uploads`. Здесь `*****.info` - папка сайта, совпадающая с доменом. Думаю, у вас будет то же самое - указываете в этом поле папку, куда загружаете все свои медиафайлы, сохраняете эти настройки - и все ОК.

Comment: Ответ тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/Как-правильно-перенести-сайт-на-wordpress/ (еле добрался до сути вопроса.. Пиши меньше, но по существу. И не засоряй вопросы разными не нужным инфохламом типа приветствий и спасиб.)